# Django - get model instance from a custom field

Tags: django, django-models

For a new project I defined a custom field `EncryptedField`. In this field, I use the methods `get_prep_value` and `from_db_value`. In these methods, I have access to the value of the field, so I can encrypt and decrypt it. I also need the value of another field of the model where EncryptedField is used for the encryption/decryption. So is it possible to have access to the instance of the model that calls my custom field `EncryptedField`. Like that I can have access to the other field value. Or there is an other way to get the other field value in these methods?

I tried to use `contribute_to_class` but it seems to not be adapted to get the model instance.

Here the code:

```py
class EncryptedField(models.TextField):

    def __init__(self, other_field, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field = other_field
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        # I try to get the value of the other field
        associated_data = ??? 
        decrypt(value, associated_data)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        # I try to get the value of the other field
        associated_data = ??? 
        encrypt(value, associated_data)
```

Comment: Please add your code here to get a good help from others.

Comment: Plese check the answer. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

`'contribute_to_class'` isn't needed to access the instance, but you can define it to add the custom field to the model class. You have to pass the instance of the model to the methods `'get_prep_value'` and `'from_db_value'` as arguments, like so:

```
class EncryptedField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, other_field_name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field_name = other_field_name
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value, instance=None):
        other_field_value = getattr(instance, self.other_field_name)
        #  to encrypt value
       

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        instance = context.get('instance')
        other_field_value = getattr(instance, self.other_field_name)
        # to decrypt value

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, private_only=False, **kwargs):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only=private_only, **kwargs)
        setattr(cls, self.name, self)
```

Comment: Is `instance` a default argument of the method get_prep_value? Because I don't see it in Django documentation and when I added the code I have the issue: `getattr(): attribute name must be string` because the instance is null. 
Same thing for the arugument `context` in `from_db_value`, I have the error `from_db_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'`

Comment: No its not a default argument.  You should define it like `context=None` in your  `from_db_value `.

Comment: I tried but when I do that, `context` is None so `context.get('instance')` will not be setted. I don't understand how it can work if context is not a default value and its never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
class EncryptedField(models.TextField):

    def __init__(self, other_field, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field = other_field
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        instance = context.get('instance')
        associated_data = getattr(instance, self.other_field)
        return decrypt(value, associated_data)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        instance = getattr(self, '_instance', None)
        if instance is not None:
            associated_data = getattr(instance, self.other_field)
            return encrypt(value, associated_data)
        return value
```

Comment: `instance` is always equals to None, so I can't have access to the `other_field` value